# Virtualenv failing on python3.8 distutils import

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I upgraded to python 3.8 today but I'm having some trouble with virtualenv:

```
$ virtualenv --python=python3.8 venv
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3.8
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 25, in <module>
    import distutils.spawn
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.spawn'
```

I've tested with --python=python3.7 and it works fine.
I've run

```
pip install --upgrade virtualenv
```

But the error remains.

Can anyone help me debug this issue? I am struggling since I don't really understand how virtualenv works. When I call it, is virtualenv itself being run on the os's python interpreter (I'm on Ubuntu), or is it trying to use the 3.8 interpreter? Thanks.

I've seen a few similar github issues but they're all older. I can't see anyone else who's had this question with python3.8

Comment: Not directly an answer to your question, but have you considered using [`venv` from Python's standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) instead?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the bug with virtualenv and Python `3.8.0`. This might be a stupid question, but: Did you activate the `venv`?